# How to use `each` to add a method in multiple strings

Tags: ruby, each

I have some code and I want to reduce its size by using the `each` method but I don't know how to use it. Here is my current code.

```
e = "1000101"
k = "1101011"
a = "1100001"
n = "1101110"
s = "1110011"
h = "1101000"
print e.to_i(2).chr
print k.to_i(2).chr
print a.to_i(2).chr
print n.to_i(2).chr
print s.to_i(2).chr
print h.to_i(2).chr
```

Comment: This question isn't particularly clear. Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: A way to do this might be to store those six variables in an array of strings, rather than in six different string variables, and then loop over the array and do to_i(2).chr on each of its entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
[e, k, a, n, s, h].each { |s| print s.to_i(2).chr }
 => Ekansh
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside `each`, you can build a new string via [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
[e, k, a, n, s, h].reduce('') { |memo, binary| memo << binary.to_i(2) }
#=> "Ekansh"
```

The block appends the result of `binary.to_i(2)` to the `memo` string which initially is `''` (empty string).

Note that we don't need to call `chr` in this case, because [`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) interprets integer input as codepoints.